# Sqoop Oracle Import does not create table

Tags: oracle, hadoop, sqoop

I want to import data from an Oracle database to Hive using Sqoop. I want Sqoop to create the table into the destination Hive database.

I put the Oracle JDBC (ojdbc6.jar) into the Sqoop lib directory.

I try those 2 methods but none of them work.

```
sqoop import \
    --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}:${DB_NAME} \
    --username ${DB_USER} \
    --password ${DB_PWD} \
    --table ${INPUT_TABLE} \
    --hcatalog-home /usr/hdp/current/hive-webhcat \
    --hcatalog-database ${OUTPUT_DB} \
    --hcatalog-table ${OUTPUT_TABLE} \
    --create-hcatalog-table \
    --num-mappers 1


sqoop import  \
    --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}:${DB_NAME} \
    --username ${DB_USER} \
    --password ${DB_PWD} \
    --hive-home /usr/hdp/current/hive \
    --hive-import \
    --create-hive-table \
    --hive-table "${OUTPUT_DB}.${OUTPUT_TABLE}" \
    --table ${INPUT_TABLE}
```

I have this error message:

> ERROR tool.ImportTool: Imported Failed: There is no column found in
>   the target table input_table. Please ensure that your table name is
>   correct.

It seems Sqoop doesn't take into account the --create-hcatalog-table or --create-hive-table

However, when I import data from PostgreSQL with Sqoop, the table creation works well. Any ideas? Thanks

For information, Sqoop read well the Oracle table. I ran this command and got the good result:

```
sqoop eval \
    --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}:${DB_NAME} \
    --username ${DB_USER} \
    --password ${DB_PWD} \
    --query "select count(1) from input_table"
```

The full logs of my error:

```
16/07/21 18:08:29 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.4.0.0-169
16/07/21 18:08:29 DEBUG tool.BaseSqoopTool: Enabled debug logging.
16/07/21 18:08:29 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
16/07/21 18:08:29 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: Using Hive-specific delimiters for output. You can override
16/07/21 18:08:29 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: delimiters with --fields-terminated-by, etc.
16/07/21 18:08:29 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Loaded manager factory: org.apache.sqoop.manager.oracle.OraOopManagerFactory
16/07/21 18:08:29 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Loaded manager factory: com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory
16/07/21 18:08:29 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Trying ManagerFactory: org.apache.sqoop.manager.oracle.OraOopManagerFactory
16/07/21 18:08:29 DEBUG oracle.OraOopManagerFactory: Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop can be called by Sqoop!
16/07/21 18:08:29 INFO oracle.OraOopManagerFactory: Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop is disabled.
16/07/21 18:08:29 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Trying ManagerFactory: com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory
16/07/21 18:08:29 DEBUG manager.DefaultManagerFactory: Trying with scheme: jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:sid
16/07/21 18:08:29 DEBUG manager.OracleManager$ConnCache: Instantiated new connection cache.
16/07/21 18:08:29 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
16/07/21 18:08:29 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Instantiated ConnManager org.apache.sqoop.manager.OracleManager@7d8704ef
16/07/21 18:08:29 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
16/07/21 18:08:29 DEBUG manager.OracleManager: Using column names query: SELECT t.* FROM input_table t WHERE 1=0
16/07/21 18:08:29 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Execute getColumnInfoRawQuery : SELECT t.* FROM input_table t WHERE 1=0
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
16/07/21 18:08:30 DEBUG manager.OracleManager: Creating a new connection for jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:sid/user, using username: user
16/07/21 18:08:30 DEBUG manager.OracleManager: No connection paramenters specified. Using regular API for making connection.
16/07/21 18:08:30 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
16/07/21 18:08:30 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Using fetchSize for next query: 1000
16/07/21 18:08:30 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM input_table t WHERE 1=0
16/07/21 18:08:30 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column c1 of type [2, 10, 0]
16/07/21 18:08:30 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column c2 of type [2, 10, 0]
16/07/21 18:08:30 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column c3 of type [12, 20, 0]
16/07/21 18:08:30 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column c4 of type [2, 0, -127]
16/07/21 18:08:30 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column c5 of type [2, 0, -127]
16/07/21 18:08:30 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column c6 of type [12, 80, 0]
16/07/21 18:08:30 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column c7 of type [93, 0, 0]
16/07/21 18:08:30 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column c8 of type [12, 20, 0]
16/07/21 18:08:30 DEBUG manager.OracleManager$ConnCache: Caching released connection for jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:sid/user
16/07/21 18:08:30 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Imported Failed: There is no column found in the target table intput_table. Please ensure that your table name is correct.
```

Comment: `--hive-import` will automatically create table in hive mentioned in `--hive-table` tag. Put `-verbose` in the end of your import query (_to get extended logs_)  and share complete logs

Comment: Edited my post with the complete logs with verbose option

Comment: error in log says `target table input_table` but you have quoted `output_table`: make sure `${OUTPUT_TABLE}` and `${INPUT_TABLE}` values are correct. are all columns `int` type? - try to run without variables (using actual values) first.

Comment: I corrected the typo, The error is "target table input"_table. I tried without variable, the result is the same. I still have the same error. The columns are not all int (int, varchar and date)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, it seems that the --table parameter didn't work well for me, so I used to --query parameter instead.

```
    sqoop import \
        --connect ${DB_CNX_STR} \
        --username ${DB_USER} \
        --password ${DB_PWD} \
        --query "SELECT * FROM ${INPUT_TABLE} WHERE \$CONDITIONS" \
        --target-dir ${TARGET_DIR}/${INPUT_TABLE} \
        --hive-import \
        --hive-home "/usr/hdp/current/hive" \
        --create-hive-table \
        --hive-table "${OUTPUT_DB}.${OUTPUT_TABLE}" \
        --num-mappers 1
```